# solaris + how to verify if file isn’t update more than XX min

Tags: linux, bash, solaris, date

how to verify if file isn’t update more than 55 min?

For example, the file **IOstatDisk2.log** not update since 18:00
And now the current time is 19:00

```
 solaris1a:/var/tmp ROOT # ls -ltr IOstatDisk2.log
 -rw-r--r--   1 root    other       6 Aug  2 18:00 IOstatDisk2.log
```

So in this case I will append the line

```
echo “new cycle - file isnt update more 55 min” >> IOstatDisk2.log
```

But if the last time stamp was less than 55 min then I will not append the line

```
 echo “new cycle - file isnt update more 55 min” >> IOstatDisk2.log
```

- I work with solaris 8/9/10

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [inotify tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify). Inotifywatch can observe file(s) and send you messages when certain operations are done to those files (eg. creation, deletion, etc). So, each hour you could set a flag, and reset it with the call from inotify. An example from `man inotifywatch`:

Watching the `~/.beagle' directory for 60 seconds:

```
   % inotifywatch -v -e access -e modify -t 60 -r ~/.beagle
   Establishing watches...
   Setting up watch(es) on /home/rohan/.beagle
   OK, /home/rohan/.beagle is now being watched.
   Total of 302 watches.
   Finished establishing watches, now collecting statistics.
   Will listen for events for 60 seconds.
   total  access  modify  filename
   1436   1074    362     /home/rohan/.beagle/Indexes/FileSystemIndex/PrimaryIndex/
   1323   1053    270     /home/rohan/.beagle/Indexes/FileSystemIndex/SecondaryIndex/
   303    116     187     /home/rohan/.beagle/Indexes/KMailIndex/PrimaryIndex/
   261    74      187     /home/rohan/.beagle/TextCache/
   206    0       206     /home/rohan/.beagle/Log/
   42     0       42      /home/rohan/.beagle/Indexes/FileSystemIndex/Locks/
   18     6       12      /home/rohan/.beagle/Indexes/FileSystemIndex/
   12     0       12      /home/rohan/.beagle/Indexes/KMailIndex/Locks/
   3      0       3       /home/rohan/.beagle/TextCache/54/
   3      0       3       /home/rohan/.beagle/TextCache/bc/
   3      0       3       /home/rohan/.beagle/TextCache/20/
   3      0       3       /home/rohan/.beagle/TextCache/62/
```

I believe inotify as such may not be available on Solaris, but here's an [article on an equivalent](https://solarisrants.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/solaris-file-event-notification/)(?)